# Twilio incoming call refresh the page call disconnected with browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

We are using the Twilio call feature in our product and we currently are facing an issue with Calling. When an incoming call is ringing on the browser and lets say the web app is opened in multiple tabs and the user refreshes any of the tabs while ringing then it will disconnect the incoming call. Our Web APP is build in the .Net MVC Framework. Please guide us if there is a way to prevent the disconnection of Twilio Call.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you enable the [`closeProtection` option](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#deviceoptions) when you instantiate your `Device`. That will enable a dialog prompt with the text:

> A call is currently in progress. Leaving or reloading the page will end the call.

when closing a page with an active connection.

```js
const device = new Device(token, {
  closeProtection: true
});
```

Comment: we can save the incoming call connections.?

Comment: You can’t store a connection across page refreshes, which is why `closeProtection` warns about that and stops the page refresh.

Comment: It's not related to page refresh, Can you give me any link to store incoming connections currently I am using this for an incoming call.
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (connection) {} With in function i am calling other process for popup model for pick up the call etc

Comment: I don’t believe you can transfer an object like that, particularly one with a live WebRTC connection to another context, like to another window. If you want to handle calls in a pop up, you should open that window first and connect to the Twilio service from that window.